# Cannot get data using requests.get

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to get the name of a stock from a web page.

I sent the query using `requsts`

```
data = requests.get(r'http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php?code=5').text
```

In normal situation, 'data' should contain 'HSBC HOLDINGS' but it does not.

```
'HSBC HOLDINGS' in data # False
```

What's wrong with my code?

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you try examining the `data` variable in a debugger, or even by printing it? Why not? Or reading the Requests documentation?

Comment: I have changed the url now. It is strange that I cannot get the page containing the data I saw in browser.

Comment: I see no `"HSBC HOLDINGS"` even if to open page in browser. What exact data do you want to extract?

Comment: You may need to refresh the page to see `HSBC HOLDINGS`.

Comment: Have you thought that `HSBC HOLDINGS` is out of top 5. If you only want to get the data from rank list, so you can keep using `requests`.

Comment: Here, `5` is the stock number of `HSBC HOLDINGS`. It does not mean top 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `referer` header to get required output:

```
data = requests.get(r'http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php?code=5', headers={'referer': 'http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php?code=00005'}).text
'HSBC HOLDINGS' in data
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
'HSBC HOLDINGS' in data.text
```

Edit: I did not see you already used '.text' in the first line. For me your code returns true. What is your return, when you print(data)?

Comment: Sorry that I missed the `.text` keyword in my question. What about the new url in my question now?

Comment: I think the knew one does not contain 'HSBC HOLDINGS'

Comment: When pasting the link in browser, you can see that. You may need to refresh the browser.